# PostgREST - Timed out acquiring connection from connection pool - optimize db-pool setting

Tags: postgrest

I am running postgREST on a production server.  The server is on AWS with 8 cores and 128GB RAM.  I have noticed that during heavy load I see "Timed out acquiring connection from connection pool" 503 errors.  The postgREST documentation discusses options to resolve this with one of the options being to increase db-pool setting (Already doing the rest.)   https://postgrest.org/en/v12/references/connection_pool.html

Is a db-pool size of 30 too much?  How do I determine the optimal db-pool size?